# Can iphone app be developed in any other language?

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if iphone apps can be developed in any other programming languages like java or C#?

Regards,
Arvind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/), which was specifically developed for this purpose. Note that you do not need to use Jailbreaking on the iphone to run a Monotouch-build application.

However, you should know before you decide on a programming platform that Apple has taken a very aggressive stance against cross-plattform developers and de facto forbidden usage of such frameworks on the Iphone.

Comment: +1 essentially, this answer is "Technically, yes; by Apple's book, no."

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want them to run without Jailbreaking.

> Applications must be originally written in Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine, and only code written in C, C++, and Objective-C may compile and directly link against the Documented APIs (e.g., Applications that link to Documented APIs through an intermediary translation or compatibility layer or tool are prohibited).

— http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/04/apple-takes-aim-at-adobe-or-android.ars